# Do clones deal critical hits?

Tags: diablo-iii

Wizards in Diablo 3 have this great skill where you clone yourself, but I couldn't find out if they could deal critical hits like I can.

Do these clones have this kind of ability?
Do they get any benefits from my critical chance?
Do they crit when I do?

Answer (score 2):

You mean [Mirror Image](http://www.diablowiki.net/Mirror_Image).

No, your clones normally deal NO damage. They are only good for distraction.

Only with the [Mirror Mimics](http://www.diablowiki.net/Mirror_Mimics) rune, they deal 10% damage, and crits apply here, too.

[Frost Nova](http://www.diablowiki.net/Frost_Nova) synergizes with this one, so that, your mirror images have a 25% chance to crit, and, when they do, they freeze the enemy. 
Still, 10% of your total damage is applied.